# What are the minimum connection times at Jeddah airport?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airports, international-travel, saudi-airlines

I will be travelling from Bangalore to London via Jeddah with Saudi Arabian Airlines.

Bangalore to Jeddah flight SV867 lands around 12:30 AM and Jeddah to London flight SV113 departs around 2 AM.

I am unsure about which terminals these flights operate from.

Can someone please advise whether this time would be sufficient ?

Answer (score 1):

If you bought it as one ticket, then it will be sufficient, but it looks a bit tight. (Although I expect it's a common connection.) The airline will re-accommodate you if you miss the connection.

The minimum connect time in this circumstance is 1 hour 30 minutes.

Int-Int on SV at JED:

```
STANDARD.D/D...D/I...I/D...I/I.
ONLINE   1.15  2.30  2.30  1.30
OFFLINE  1.15  2.30  2.30  1.30
** OR * ARE ALL
SV-SV II  1.05 FLT   60 - FLT  301 YYZ - CAI 
SV-SV II  2.10 FLT   60 - FLT  758 YYZ - DEL 
SV-SV II  1.35 FLT   60 - FLT  768 YYZ - MAA 
SV-SV II  2.30 FLT   34 - FLT  680 
SV-SV II  1.35 FLT  164 - FLT  766 
SV-SV II  2.00 FLT  681 - FLT   21 
SV-SV II  2.00 FLT  681 - FLT   55 
SV-SV II  1.10 FLT  829 - FLT  163 
SV-SV II  1.25 FLT  829 - FLT  181 
SV-SV II  3.00 TRM N  - ** ALL - UNITED STATES  
SV-SV II  1.30 ALL - UNITED STATES  
**-SV II  3.00 ALL - UNITED STATES  
**-SV II  3.00 TRM N  - S  
SV-** II  3.00 TRM S  - N
```

Saudia operates from the South terminal. (During the Hajj season things may be a bit hectic but non-pilgrims still deplane into the South terminal before pilgrims are decanted into the special Hajj terminal.)

Answer (score 1):

You are more than okay with the transit time because:

1. Jeddah is the main hub for Saudia; so there are plenty of connecting flights (in case you miss your connection).
2. You don't have to go through customs and immigration; there is no airside transit visas or such formalities in Saudi Arabia.
3. The terminal is huge, but easily navigable. You may have to resort to a brisk walk.
4. Calchas mentioned Hajj, but there is a dedicated Hajj terminal at Jeddah which is only used for Hajj flights. You should be okay.

Comment: I think SV only has one flight to LHR each day

Comment: There are 3 flights from Dammam to London-Heathrow; 3 from Jeddah; 5 from Riyadh; and 3 from Madiah (MED)

Comment: I did mean ex-JED, sorry for the confusion (I don't think SV could arrange a transit visa to get you to another airport). I only see SV 113 on JED-LHR, what are the other two? [I don't think they are going to endorse your ticket onto another carrier.]